# Django celery connection refuses

Tags: django, celery

When i am giving this command on terminal- 
celery worker

getting this error-
.py:161: CDeprecationWarning: 
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
```

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.

```
  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

 -------------- celery@hiteshdhanwani-Inspiron-N5010 v3.1.17 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.16.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.10-utopic
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7fd33e57a190 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[2015-03-14 11:05:40,177: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2015-03-14 11:05:42,191: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...

[2015-03-14 11:05:46,210: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds...
```

Comment: What's problem you'd like help with? The connection error or understanding the warning?

Comment: are you install rabbitmq-server ?

Comment: We are not using rabbitmq-server, so we have not installed it

Comment: Which message broker will you be using? Celery requires a solution to send and receive messages; usually this comes in the form of a separate service called a message broker.